# Meteor tutorial doesn't update MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

IM trying out Meteor ToDo-list tutorial but I have problem where I have a form and I should be able to insert the values into the database but it doesn't work. When I hit enter nothing happens.

Here my my html:

```
<head>
  <title>Todo list</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <h1>Tee asjad ära!</h1>
        <form class="new-task">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Type to add new tasks" />
        </form>
    </header>

        <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
            {{> task}}
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

<template name="task">
<li>{{text}}</li>
</template>
```

here is the .js file:

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
//see kood jookseb ainult kliendipoolel
  Template.body.helpers({
     tasks: function () {
      return Tasks.find({});
    }
  });

  Template.body.events({
    "submit .new-task": function (event) {
      var text = event.target.text.value;
      Tasks.insert({
        text: text,
        createdAt: new Date()

      });

      event.target.text.value = "";
      return false;
    } 
  });
}
```

When I enter values from command line to the database it works fine.

Comment: Is console.log(event.target.text.value) returning correct value? And how do you submit this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input is missing `name="text"`, which is the attribute that lets you access the value through `event.target.text.value`.

Were you getting an error in the JavaScript console in your browser?